# Setup online discussion forum

Tags: chat, forum

I am planning to setup an online discussion forum for our research group to share and discuss technical issues and information with each other. In the order of priority, following are the desired features:

1. Private forum open to limited users
2. Publish posts; create threads, topic folders
3. Upload
4. Instant messaging/chat

Additional Info:
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit
Hardware: 8 GB RAM

I'm curious if above features are possible without hosting a website since I have no prior experience and knowledge of the same.

Please make your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Need more info about your requirements. OS? Kind of hardware? Do you have any experience with similar tools? Have you looked at any packages yet, and found any pros or cons?

Comment: OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Hardware: 64-bit operating system, 8 GB RAM
I'm curious if above features are possible without hosting a website since I have no prior experience and knowledge of the same.

Comment: Post additional info as an edit to your Question rather than as a Comment.